# Does marking e-mails as spam help other Mac users?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, monterey, spam

Sometimes there's a spam e-mail in my inbox. I just have to click the spam button and the e-mail will get moved to the Junk folder. Some emails even land in the Junk folder automatically.

I assume over time Apple Mail learns and gets better in recognizing spam and will be better in automatically filtering it. That is right, isn't it?

Will marking an e-mail as spam also help other users spam filter? Does Apple has something like a spam filter that learns more the more users mark their e-mails as spam? Or does marking an e-mail as spam only influence the spam filter on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Mail will not share spam filtering directly with other Mac users.

If you use iCloud for email, and mark something as spam (regardless of in Mail or another email client), then iCloud will learn this and apply it appropriately. Apple does not specify whether this learning is shared across users.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202315

Comment: So marking e-mails as spam in my non iCloud accounts definitely doesn't help other users, right?

Comment: Well, I suppose your email provider could do a similar thing as iCloud does - detect "moving to junk" as a signal for junk mail. But whether they do is based on your provider, not the mail app.

Comment: I often see a notice on emails in my Gmail spam folder saying "Lots of users have marked this domain as spam in the past." I assume this also applies when moving stuff to your Gmail spam using Apple Mail.

Comment: Yes, that should be sufficient